# Breeze is not working with some project settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, breeze, hottowel

I have a problem using breeze on a project based on John Papa's HotTowel. I configured breeze like:

```
var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager('breeze/Breeze');
```

everything is ok but in the case I change the Project properties `Start Action` from `Current Page` to `Specific Page: HotTowel/Index` and breeze doesn't work properly.

I've checked the requests using firebug. It seems in this case application sends a `GET` request like this:

```
http://localhost:53180/HotTowel/Index/breeze/Breeze/Metadata
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:53180/breeze/Breeze/Metadata
```

I've also checked this part of `breeze.js` which is going to send get request.
The `url` parameter is set to `breeze/Breeze/Metadata` in both cases which seems correct.

```
  ctor.prototype.fetchMetadata = function (metadataStore, dataService) {   
  var serviceName = dataService.serviceName;
  var url = dataService.makeUrl("Metadata");
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var that = this;
  ajaxImpl.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',...
```

I've also tried `~/breeze/Breeze` but it didn't work as remote service name.

As I'm new to web, probably it's not related to breeze.
The question is why the ajax call (or breeze) depends on how the project activates?

Comment: See the answer to a similar question on StackOverflow [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767387/breeze-entity-manager-relative-path/23788779#23788779).

Answer (score 1):

Add a `/` character to your configuration to execute the request relative to the base directory:

```
var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager('/breeze/Breeze');
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is because you specified a relative path for the EntityManager and if your url is localhost:53180/HotTowel/Index then the relative url for the EntityManager is localhost:53180/HotTowel/Index + /breeze/Breeze.

To correct the issue, change your EntityManager path to the following:

```
var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager('breeze/Breeze');
```

Comment: As I said in the second line of the answer, I've just declared the mgr as you said and it's not working.