# Breeze Entity manager relative path

Tags: iis, breeze, relative-path, single-page-application, hottowel

A similar question is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17337292/807223) but with no solution. I am able to run my project on localhost but once deployed, loading the metadata fails. Looking into chrome developper tools, the request is sent to `http://www.domain.org/breeze/metadata` instead of `http://www.domain.org/projectname/breeze/metadata`. On my localhost, the metadata loads as `http://localhost:xxxx/breeze/Metadata`. My entity manager is declared as `new breeze.EntityManager('breeze')`. If I change the entitymanager to `new breeze.EntityManager('projectname/breeze')` all works fine but it does not work on my localhost.  How can I declare the entity manager so that the path is relative to the project and works on my localhost and when deployed?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can assume that the data server and the web server share the same origin. Therefore, you can construct the origin (whatever that is) from the browser's `window.location` object (inject `$location` in Angular):

```
var origin = location.protocol+'//'+location.host+'/'; // 'ex: http://www.foo.com:3000/'
var projectName = location.hostname === 'localhost' ? '' : 'projectName/';
var serviceName = origin + projectName + 'breeze'.
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
```

Alternatively, you could delegate the task to the web server which could construct the service name and plunk it in the web page as a JavaScript variable that you pick up during client-side configuration.

I'm sure you can take it from here if you need to make other assumptions.